# Unexpected Symbol Error in lapply

Tags: r, lapply

Ok, I am basically trying to delete rows of the list element `data_csv` by running the following code in R and I get the error that follows:

```
a <- lapply(data_csv, funtion(x) x[!delete_row(x)])
```

> ```
> Error: unexpected symbol in "a <- lapply(data_csv, funtion(x) x"
> ```

`delete_row` is a custom function I wrote. It is as follows:

```
delete_row <- function(x){
    if (sum(is.na(x[1,8:11])) > 2 || 
        sum(is.na(data_csv[iter, 12:15])) > 2 || 
        sum(is.na(data_csv[iter,16:19])) > 2){
        return(TRUE)
    } 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is `function` and not `funtion`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @akrun for pointing out the error:
It was a syntax error of misspelling function

Comment: excellent observation.